# Leader command in Vrapper for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, vim

I've been using vrapper in Eclipse, and the leader key doesn't seem to work.

I looked at the documentation and didn't see anything about it.  Is the command not

```
    let mapleader = ','
```

Comment: Have you sent an e-mail to the project owner?  He's very good at getting back to feature requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vrapper is not vim: don't expect anything you are accustomed to in vim to work in vrapper or any other vim emulator.

`<leader>` is useful for configuration purpose because `mapleader` can be changed at runtime but that could be seen as a drawback by some... Anyway, these two mappings behave the same way so, if you don't use `<leader>`  for very specific reasons, using the second one should be enough:

```
nnoremap <leader>a dosomething
nnoremap ,a dosomething
```

Comment: Now that I'm thinking about it, what advantages does the <Leader> key provide over just using the comma?  Is it just changing it at runtime?

Comment: @Brandon I'm joining in late, but the advantage is only there in Vim plugins (and hence only in Vim): since the `.vimrc` gets loaded before any plugin scripts you can define your `mapleader`. Any plugins which then use `<Leader>` will correctly get bound to that prefix key so that they don't conflict as easily with your custom keys. Note that Vrapper doesn't support Vim plugins, so `<Leader>` was never implemented.